# How to Detect collisions in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt6

Iam making a simple game using PyQt, but i don't know how i can detect the collisions between enemy and bullets, there is a C++ implementation, but i dont know how i can do that in PyQt. and it should be done in Bullet.py file.
these are the files.

Window.py

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QGraphicsScene,QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsItem
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
import sys
from Player import Player
from Enemy import Enemy


class Window(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

    self.setFixedSize(800, 600)
    self.create_scene()

    self.show()




def create_scene(self):
    self.scene = QGraphicsScene()

    #create an item to put in the scene
    player = Player()

    #make rect focusable
    player.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsFocusable)
    player.setFocus()


    #by default QGraphicsRectItem has 0 length and width
    player.setRect(0,0, 100,100)

    #add item to the scene
    self.scene.addItem(player)

    #set size of the scene
    self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 800, 600)

    #set the player at the botoom
    player.setPos(self.width() / 2, self.height() - player.rect().height())
     
     # create our score
    score = Score()
    self.scene.addItem(score)

    self.setScene(self.scene)

    self.timer = QTimer()
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.spawn)
    self.timer.start(2000)


def spawn(self):
    enemy = Enemy()
    self.scene.addItem(enemy)


App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window() 
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Player.py

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QGraphicsRectItem
from PyQt6.QtGui import QKeyEvent
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from Bullet import MyBullet




class Player(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()



def keyPressEvent(self, event: QKeyEvent):
    if (event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Left):

        if self.pos().x() > 0:
            self.setPos(self.x() - 10, self.y())

    elif (event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Right):
        if (self.pos().x() + 100 < 800):
            self.setPos(self.x() + 10, self.y())


    elif (event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Space):
        mybullet = MyBullet()
        mybullet.setPos(self.x(), self.y())
        self.scene().addItem(mybullet)
```

Enemy.py

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QGraphicsRectItem
from random import randint
from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer


class Enemy(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    random_number = randint(10,1000) % 700
    self.setPos(random_number , 0)


    self.setRect(0,0,100,100)

    self.timer = QTimer()
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.move)
    self.timer.start(50)




def move(self):
    #move enemy to down
    self.setPos(self.x(), self.y()+5)

    if self.pos().y() + self.rect().height() < 0:
        self.scene().removeItem(self)
        print("Bullet deleted")
```

Bullet.py

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsItem
from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer
from Enemy import Enemy




class MyBullet(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    score = Score() 

    self.setRect(0,0,10,50)

    self.timer = QTimer()
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.move)
    self.timer.start(50)


def move(self):
    
    #This is the place for the collision 
    colliding = self.collidingItems()
    for item in colliding:
        if isinstance(item, Enemy):
            #increase the score
            score.increase()
            self.scene().removeItem(item)
            self.scene().removeItem(self)


    self.setPos(self.x(), self.y() - 10)

    if self.pos().y() + self.rect().height() < 0:
        self.scene().removeItem(self)
        print("Bullet deleted")
```

Score.py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QGraphicsTextItem
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt

```
from PyQt6.QtGui import QFont

class Score(QGraphicsTextItem):

    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()

    self.score = 0

    #draw the text
    self.setPlainText("Score : " + str(self.score))
    self.setDefaultTextColor(Qt.GlobalColor.red)
    self.setFont(QFont("Sanserif", 18))



def increase(self):
    self.score += 1
    self.setPlainText(str(self.score))
    print(self.score)
```

This is the C++ code, i want similiar of that for Python.

```
QList<QGraphicsItem *> colliding_items = collidingItems();
for (int i = 0, n = colliding_items.size(); i < n; ++i) {
    if (typeid(*(colliding_items[i])) == typeid(Enemy)) {
        scene->removeItem(colliding_items[i]);
        scene->removeItem(this);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QGraphicsItem` has `collidingItems` method that use `QGraphicsItem.boundingRect()` to detect collisions. It is implemented for `QGraphicsRectItem`. So you only need to call it and iterate over items.

```py
class MyBullet(QGraphicsRectItem):
    
    def move(self):
        colliding = self.collidingItems()
        for item in colliding:
            if isinstance(item, Enemy):
                self.scene().removeItem(item)
                self.scene().removeItem(self)
                return
```

Comment: Now when the bullet collide with the enemy, it is giving me this error the app crashes.       self.scene().removeItem(Enemy)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'removeItem'   , but when i change the import in Bullet.py like this (from Game.Enemy import Enemy), there is no crashes, but the bullet and the enemy is not removing after collision, and i want after collision both of them should be removed

Comment: also when i bring my mouse cursor in this code self.scene().removeItem(Enemy), it is showing me this message (expected type QGraphicsItem, got Type[Enemy] instead )

Comment: Sorry,  `removeItem(item)` not `removeItem(Enemy)`, updated code. You need to import `Enemy`, of cource

Comment: Thanks, but again the same error self.scene().removeItem(item)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'removeItem' , i don't know why it is telling that there is no removeItem. i have imported the Enemy class

Comment: Sorry, another mistake, you need to remove item first then remove self

Comment: Hello i have faced another problem, i have added a Score class, i want when the Enemy and bullet is removed i want to increase the score by one, after creating the Score class i have added that class in the Window.py file for adding that to the scene, also i added the increase() method in the Bullet.py file, but the text is not increasing.